# How to infer generic T in return type through a type guard and implicit inference in lower levels?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference, typescript-types

```
type Entity<T> = {payload: T};

interface IBaseDataType {name?: string};
interface IDataTypeV1 extends IBaseDataType {id: number};
interface IDataTypeV2 extends IBaseDataType {id: string};

const dataV1: IDataTypeV1[] = [{id: 1, name: '1'}, {id: 2, name: '2'}, {id: 3, name: '3'}, {id: 4, name: '4'}]
const dataV2: IDataTypeV2[] = [{id: '1', name: '1'}, {id: '2', name: '2'}, {id: '3', name: '3'}, {id: '4', name: '4'}]

const getDbItemV1 = (id: number): Entity<IDataTypeV1> => {
  return {
    payload: {
      id,
      name: dataV1.find(d => d.id === id)?.name
    }
  };
}

const getDbItemV2 = (id: string): Entity<IDataTypeV2> => {
  return {
    payload: {
      id,
      name: dataV2.find(d => d.id === id)?.name
    }
  };
}

const isString = (val: unknown): val is string => typeof val === 'string';

type DataType<T> = T extends string ? IDataTypeV2 : IDataTypeV1;

const getDbItem = <T extends string | number>(id: T): Entity<DataType<T>> 
    => isString(id) ? getDbItemV2(id) : getDbItemV1(id); // ?

       // Type 'Entity<IDataTypeV1> | Entity<IDataTypeV2>' is not assignable to type 'Entity<DataType<T>>'.
       // Type 'Entity<IDataTypeV1>' is not assignable to type 'Entity<DataType<T>>'.
       // Type 'IDataTypeV1' is not assignable to type 'DataType<T>'


const getItem = (id: number) => getDbItem(id);

console.log(getItem(3)); // this works and getItem(3) infers to  Entity<IDataTypeV1> and V1 is associated with number param for id, so it seems okay, but the return line in getDbItem throws type error
```

TypeScript playground link for better visual cue what's happening: [initial playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqAPAFQHxQLxQN5gCGIANgPaEAmAXFGgL4DcAUM4ghAE4BmhAxtACSAIUIBnCABFCwQmnDQ8cQgFsIAflpjgndgHMmbDj35Dps+ZABqARigQAHsAhxKYqCPFSZchfkQ0UHAArioARlyG7M4mAh7mvtYATPZOLm4eohIJlooBWjr6hsx8ZHDaUJQ+trSCOQq2ANoAujhQjXj5UDYANEGqELQA5DZD9H2dgUl9ymrDSWMTXQDMMwPDy4v+gQAsa3NQQztjzSVlFVWyVkm19cktbR1dI0P7g4ej49vzr-0HQwsvpMNr9Zu8hpsgc9jm9hsd6KczuVgFA9BBgJIwoJnCpbG0ABRdELhLgASlo8CQqDqPlytiw2CweGYUCgnHRwU4cHwLNZUCIpAogWZfL5AR6vNFYNol0ItgAdNx2JR8ZQcFhKPKAjhsLgAqT1PKwZKoPReYYzUiKmiMVicdcCV1tLo4HpybAEMgQCgaRYGkkGUzeezgJzuSK+QLyFRaBHReKTazpZVqklFcrVerKlq1bq9ZQDUaBiazayLaxSsioIgxABlQqugkAN0IJFowTgAGs4GQAO5wd0tkjV9zO-RZ0CQMjcKBDnW4IZj11DFjMSfQO4QdAMuipZyuUcNvRQdTxWn+qC3c-WGyryvW9GY7EQFRtdB79KHl3HgA+QVCEScBghKBGg7qUl6KCbtugYjvW34gaSJ6oo+dovtciGXihtrPriNiIXe5wojauGOoExKAUhjLYU+OIERW5xkCQEDyuQej4iRdHLKSpKMEAA)

EDIT: Thanks for the reply, can you check this playground again (last line): [updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqAPAFQHxQLxQN5RgCGIANgPZEAmAXFGlAL4DcAUK4ghAE4BmRAY2gBJAEJEAzhAAiRYETThoeVlChwiAWwgB+OhODdOAczaMOXPoJGz5iyADUAjFAgAPYBDhUJUMZJk5BSV8VShEWnUAV00AIx4zC08rIT9bYMcAJlcPLx8-cSl0+2UwiP1DE0TWAXI4AygqIOc6YWKlZwBtAF0cKE6wgnKoJwAadS0IOgByJ2mmUcHwyMzxjW0ZzPnGRbUhyIBmNcmZg+3d-GW6ABZjjahp6-PWbrZa+uBG5szW9qyevoDPZXB5zO5TUHPYHDaZbcGbKGXGFneEPM4LJYwp6ox7PV7sd4NYwQYDSWLCTyaZx9AAUwzgMXi3AAlHR4EhUG0giVnFhsFgVGpuCSotw4KE1GpiGRKJFBZK1BELgr1hCmvJnAA6XicKg0mlUZk4LBUTURHDYXARZk6TWq5UYtQsVjOmp1IkkskUiBU7K4OmRAxGODGVmwBDIEAoLl2DqZPkCsLC4Ci8XyqUkCjUOjpyVKsIqk5fDWZbW6-WG42NM1UC1Ww22+0Fx1MMxsN0fcISADKlRDtIAbkRSHQonAANZwcgAdzgYaHpC7UCDJiroEg5F4UAXdYeK5D03bAHoj1AAIJUKgQWvAAAWiF8vHI3Cgmmf0GJcB4iAEUCiEiIYlWHXaBCggEoAFkiDAdAck8bxfHIWIACsIAEYBxgAVTgvJEJQtDgD5CVlz7YwcygECKmDUwoGTVM6AYZ01AZOIeHIyjolY7hmFokUxTobDnVdED6CUKCwD6MDIOg6M-ggBxVjSbkOicDBj1PHQdFYE8oEJT5eDHAQJBzbTTzUToAGlwnFccIBATdRMgcTujoGlTIVEFpLASzuk6aYQOmbpFh0tQjX5cMOSjLyfL8uixUCtT3MYPoVBCkjqLoYlSXJSkFOCszOKZTLPRyn1nHy1t2BEuT0CIhh3Hg-J92MKAdCU2MsigX5lMcJw3ndT4sq9Sk+lghrcKgWz7K3LyMDcxVImitBfP8pRAsWMN2UjdAxOgzpltivi4AS40yh7UiAyNNqhtK31Lq6qAbu9KknEu9sROehSUome5msqjsPWAZ7aXpRkeDCrAnspN6CXdchSAgTUKGMGksuemkDmZTVpSzU1rR4nS72gc0H0KngoAAH3S1cAFpdKIcU71J+JrN4HhhVrXhuHITQKNvD8Sue6ZfAAJSOkplx5iBbxnLSgA)

**EDIT**: What if the id is not `number | string`, but there are separate `numberId: number | null` and `stringId: string | null`. How to make the typing properly?

**Potential answer** to my question (still not strictly inferred ReturnType): [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqAPAFQHxQLxQN5RgCGIANgPZEAmAXFGlAL4DcAUK4ghAE4BmRAY2gBJAEJEAzhAAiRYETThoeVlChwiAWwgB%20OhODdOAczaMOXPoJGz5iyADUAjFAgAPYBDhUJUMZJk5BSV8VShEWnUAV00AIx4oAB9o0lIzC08rIT9bYMcAJlcPLx8-cSlc%202UwiP1DEySUtNZzVgFyOAMoKiDnOmFKpWcAbQBdHChhsIJaqCcAGnUtCDoAcidVpnnp8Mj8xY1tNfzNxm21GciAZgPltavT8-xdugAWW6OoVdfH1lG2dqdYDdXr5fqDApjCZTC4vL4bD4reG-WGzVYnRHHFHPNEPTFfB5bHZon7476-f7sQFdYwQYDSWLCTyaZwTAAUszgMXi3EaXNSAEo6PAkKgBkEqs4sNgsCo1Nw6VFuHBQmo1MQyJRInK1WoIk9dYckT15M4AHS8ThUNlsqgCnBYKhmiI4bC4CICnRmo0GolqFgtNhtDo0ukMpkQFmFXAcyIGIxwYx8qKC4UIZAgFDiuxDfLS2VhBXAJUqnXqkgUah0Mtq-VhQ13EGm-IWq02u0O7rOqiu912r0%20%20t%20phmIPU4GICQAZXqifZADciKQ6FE4ABrODkADucCFUEXpHCvnjDRlUFAkHIvH3S97XxPidWQYA9M%20oABBKhUCA94AAC0nKBeHIXlNBA6BaTgHhEAEKAogkIhaVYC9oHKCAqgAWSIMB0CKTxvF8chYgAKwgARgEWABVPCSkIkiyOAaVVSgB9jGrc8lDqBNTCgIsSzoBgAzULk4h4diULoESeWYXjFWVOhqIDAMUPoJQsLACY0Mw7CswhCAHH2HIJSGJwMDHENgVpelGWZCZcPcfDSjXCAQCvVTIHUjA2TCKSeGESIYA8bhBGAdA1Ow4Y0FGYZVhQ1ZRgObkeCwZJ%20VIJ5WP84UgpCsKPIiqKYrihKWNnYwUqaVg9xFDM8ogdTIui1Y%20OVeL8xqacyrZTKOx0KArPDZkDO6sr-PtOgBpsyNnDZXzuH8qBJGiUTuAFIMVIjKMJgII0uIaANgyBfq6U29k5qy5aeWTVJFh6va51SlNSHtM9Js22akvmqhbtGu1zM6chSAgM0KGMNkrPem4mgFM0NUrJ0PRk19zz-aAXUAubGlY67DwAWigAQiBVf9APicI4F4HgFR7XhuHITQUYgsMps0VZfAAJTkuAqhY%20mID-bcdFYIA)

```
type BaseTypeMap<T extends object, U extends object> = {
  string: { type: string; return: T };
  number: { type: number; return: U };
};
type TypeMap = BaseTypeMap<IDataTypeV2, IDataTypeV1>;

const getDbItem = <T extends keyof TypeMap>(
  numberId: Extract<TypeMap[T]['type'], number> | null,
  stringId: Extract<TypeMap[T]['type'], string> | null
): Entity<TypeMap[T]['return']> =>
  isString(stringId) ? getDbItemV2(stringId) : getDbItemV1(numberId as number);

// Entity<TypeMap[T]['return']> infers number | string | null instead of number (when numberId is not null) or string (when stringId is not null) - that's my goal but I guess impossible
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZV0em) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I had to try this in the real codebase because I created a prototype for the purpose of this question. It works like a charm! This is a little bit too advanced for me because I still haven't had a lot of use cases for the T extends keyof K -> K[T] typing and I've only seen it in the books, and the Map adds extra complexity on top of this, so I would definitely appreciate a more explained answer! Thank you!

Comment: Sure, will do as soon as I get a chance. Currently on mobile

Comment: One additional question - in the last line where we call console.log(getItem(3).payload.id); the id is of union number | string. Can this be inferred as well in the return type? This would be amazing. Added an EDIT in the post with a new link to help you understand what I mean

Comment: Honestly, this won't be possible with just one parameter. If you could also pass the type of the parameter like `getDbItem('number', id)` then I can do that, otherwise how would you like to proceed?

Comment: I wish there was a way to infer one of the 2 types in the union like with a type guard but I guess union will do it. I can't pass the type because I wanted to automate it to return a specific type based on the parameter's type. You say return the type as param - wouldn't this be available in the typing as typeof id, so the users won't have to write it explicitly. There will be more than 400 places to do this split between v1 and v2 versions of the functions based on the type of the id parameter and instead of doing if-else 400 times I tried to automate it, but I guess it won't be 100% possible

Comment: unfortunately, `typeof id` will break the connection in the types

Comment: What if there are 2 parameters - numberId: number | null, stringId: string | null - can we get a strictly inferred return type based on which of the 2 is not null or something like this? If not, you can write something and I will approve it :) You helped enough. I would appreciate if you give an example with 2 nullable ids of type string and number

Comment: It's pretty late for me. Will check tomorrow. Can you include a test case for that situation? Im not suee if I understood

Comment: @wonderflame getDbItem(numberId: number | null, stringId: string | null): Entity<IDataTypeV1 | IDataTypeV2>; if numberId is null -> the return type to be Entity<IDataTypeV2> and if it's not null (so it's number) the return type becomes Entity<IDataTypeV1>. And if this is still not possible (for the reasons above) - how can I add 2 ids with your initial approach const getDbItem = <T extends keyof TypeMap>(
  id: TypeMap[T]['type'] // 1 id for nullable string, 1 for nullable number
): Entity<TypeMap[T]['return']> =>
  isString(id) ? getDbItemV2(id) : getDbItemV1(id); 
I would accept any help

Comment: Added last edit of the question with playground and potential outcome of this discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use assertion for the return types of the 2 calls

```
// const getDbItem = <T extends string | number>(id: T): Entity<DataType<T>> => isString(id) ? getDbItemV2(id) : getDbItemV1(id); // Error: Type 'IDataTypeV1' is not assignable to type 'DataType<T>'.

const getDbItem = <T extends string | number>(id: T): Entity<DataType<T>> 
       => isString(id) 
          ? getDbItemV2(id) as Entity<DataType<T>> 
          : getDbItemV1(id) as Entity<DataType<T>>;

getDbItem(3).payload.id // id is infered as number
getDbItem('3').payload.id // id is infered as string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqAPAFQHxQLxQN5gCGIANgPaEAmAXFGgL4DcAUM4ghAE4BmhAxtACSAIUIBnCABFCwQmnDQ8cQgFsIAflpjgndgHMmbDj35Dps+ZABqARigQAHsAhxKYqCPFSZchfkQ0UHAArioARlyG7M4mAh7mvtYATPZOLm4eohIJlooBWjr6hsx8ZHDaUJQ+trSCOQq2ANoAujhQjXj5UDYANEGqELQA5DZD9H2dgUl9ymrDSWMTXQDMMwPDy4v+gQAsa3NQQztjzSVlFVWyVkm19cktbR1dI0P7g4ej49vzr-0HQwsvpMNr9Zu8hpsgc9jm9hsd6KczuVgFA9BBgJIwoJnCpbG0ABRdELhLgASlo8CQqDqPlytiw2CweGYUCgnHRwU4cHwLNZUCIpAogWZfL5AR6vNFYNol0ItgAdNx2JR8ZQcFhKPKAjhsLgAqT1PKwZKoPReYYzUiKmiMVicdcCV1tLo4HpybAEMgQCgaRYGkkGUzeezgJzuSK+QLyFRaBHReKTazpZVqklFcrVerKlq1bq9ZQDUaBiazayLaxSsioIgxABlQqugkAN0IJFowTgAGs4GQAO5wd0tkjV9zO-RZ0CQMjcKBDnW4IZj11DFjMSfQO4QdAMuipZyuUcNvRQdTxWn+qC3c-WGyrgD0d6glet6Mx2IgKja6D36UPLuPAA+QShBEnAYISgRoO6lJeigm7boGI71v+EGkieqKvnaH7XKhl4Yba764jYqGMFAD6wJwnBkJwtC5IcvqJBAthDCOQRkCi4hiIgejKGEJDQMAZBQOuhzwZgQzyhW5wojab44l+aA-geUBLoBwEkmBEG0dBnqoGJGBYImrKMkhR64UZoqnrJWG4kkuHiB6VLevphmim5eHWYRtj2e4MF6deW6YBgq6eTi+LLKS8pRkKOZkY+2o1tWcDcFwEBqg5xKgcwoUfviEJDJF0VULF5EJe47Apey6V-voQA)

I'm still open to a potential answer which would eliminate the need of `as` assertions, but at this point I don't believe such thing is possible with TypeScript.

Comment: Not sure, how I missed this option, but does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBVlVN) work?

Comment: It works! Sadly in my project the convention is only arrow functions, but I appreciate your help. It works indeed

Comment: Okay, i still recommend to reconsider. *functions overloading* are very useful and the only go option in several cases. Also, assertion functions cant be an arrow function